# How to use two different socket in one page using PHP

Tags: php

I am working on websockets in php,I successfully integrated websockets for "notification module" ,Here is my code (in Localhost)

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8282');
    var client = {
        user_id: <?php echo "3"; ?>,
        recipient_id: null, 
        type: 'socket',
        token: null,
        message: null
    };

    conn.onopen = function (e) {
        conn.send(JSON.stringify(client));
    };
    conn.onmessage = function (e) {
        // our code...
    }
```

Now i just want to ask,if i want to integrate/use another socket in same page then for this what should i do ?

Comment: This doesn't look like PHP code.

Comment: This is JavaScript, not php. But anyway if you want to connect to another socket, then simply make another connection object. It's unclear where the problem is?